# Does the site need a "martial-arts" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've already removed the tag from the following questions:

- [Best weight lifting exercise to develop a Wing Chun chain punch](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1/best-weight-lifting-exercise-to-develop-a-wing-chun-chain-punch)
- [Where can I find critical comparisons of various martial arts?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/21/where-can-i-find-critical-comparisons-of-various-martial-arts)

DIY and Electronics have blacklisted "diy" and "electronics" respectively. Presuming that this site is all about martial arts to begin with, is there a reason to keep this tag? The term itself is applicable to all questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've gone ahead and blacklisted that tag, as it is pretty redundant, like you said. :D

Answer (score 5):

I wholly support your actions; this site is martial-arts, so all questions should be related to martial arts already.  To me that means all questions have the `martial-art` tag implicitly.